# Mostrar número de elementos de un array a un Textfield

Tags: java

Quería hacer un array de un número que está en un TextField. Para llenar el array quería que tomara y guardara el número de otro TextField, luego en otro TextField mostrar cuántos elementos hay en el array dándole a un botón. Estoy aprendiendo y esta parte en un ejercicio no sé cómo resolverlo.

```
    //Queriamos tomar el numero de para que sea el tamaño del array
            int tarapoto= Integer.parseInt(txttarapoto.getText());
             
    //se supone que establecimos el tamaño del array
             int arreglito[]=new int [tarapoto];
    
    //queriamos que tomara y guardara el numero del otro TextField para que se vaya llenando el array, porque es un formulario de producto y ps necesitamos cambiar a otros datos.
             int i;
            for(i=0; i<= arreglito.length; i++){
                 int cantidad= Integer.parseInt(txtcantidad.getText());
             }
    //mostraria el numero de elementos dentro del array
            txtasientosvt.setText(String.valueOf(arreglito[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo de cómo podrías modificar tu código para mostrar la cantidad de elementos en la matriz:

```
int tarapoto = Integer.parseInt(txttarapoto.getText());
int[] arreglito = new int[tarapoto];

int arraySize = arreglito.length;

txtasientosvt.setText(String.valueOf(arraySize));
```

Ten en cuenta que en tu código, estás utilizando un for para iterar sobre los elementos de la matriz, pero en realidad no está haciendo nada con los valores de los elementos. El código anterior simplemente muestra la cantidad de elementos en la matriz, sin modificar la matriz en sí.